# Как пропорционально уменьшить две фотографии?

Tags: php

Как пропорционально уменьшить две фотографии?

Предположим есть две фотографии 1) width-690px 2) width-200px. Надо сделать так, что-бы они вместились в 480px сохраняя пропорции. Высота одинакова.

Мы имеем

```
                $height // высоту обоих изображений
                $width_1 //ширину 1 изображания
                $width_2 //ширину 2 изображания
                $ar = $width_1 / $width_2; //Их отношение
```

Comment: Вместились по ширине в 480px? Ту, которая 200px — растягивать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот общее решение для пропорционального ресайза:

```
$imagesize = getimagesize('image.jpg');
$w = $imagesize[0];  // 690
$h = $imagesize[1];  // 518 – к примеру

$w_div_h = $w / $h;  // пропорция

$w_new = 480;        // устанавливаем новую ширину
$h_new = $w_new / $w_div_h;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Kohana Image Library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/image)

Comment: а без библиотеки

Comment: @Zow а зачем ? может тогда и без imagemagic/gd ?

Comment: Ну затем что не надо ему. Рассчитать новые размеры изображения для ресайза — вполне себе нормальная задача, подключать для такого какую-то прослойку/либу/фреймворк/святагодуха — моветон, я считаю.Скоро люди будут спрашивать, как сложить два числа, а им будут фреймворки предлагать.

Comment: ну как сказать, мы и так два числа на  яву делаем, ещё живы те люди которые думали что этого не произойдет. да и ресайз вы без либы неделю писать будете на php :) btw, не смотрел как gd, а imagic вроде-бы хватает просто указания ширины или высоты результирующего изображения, чтобы растянуть.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал вот так, есть лучшие варианты?

```
   $path = "http://localhost/" .$attachments[0]['src'];
   $size = getimagesize($path);
$width_1 = (int)$size[0];
$height_1 =(int)$size[1];

$path = "http://localhost/" .$attachments[1]['src'];
$size = getimagesize($path);
        $w2 = (int)$size[0];
        $h2 =(int)$size[1];

$ar = $w2 / $h2;
$width_2 = $height_1 * $ar; //Ширина фото №2  при высоте, как у №1

$ar1 = $height_1 / $width_1; //Отношение высоты к ширине фото №1
$ar2h =  $h2 / $width_2;    //Отношение ширины к высоте фото №2

$all_width_photo = $width_2 + $width_1; //Ширина обоих фото
for($i = 450;$all_width_photo > 480;--$i){ //подставнока фотографий
    $new_height1 = $i * $ar1;       // получение высоты фото №1 при определенном i
    $new_width2 = $new_height1 / $ar2h; // получение ширины фото №2 при определенном i
    $all_width_photo =  $new_width2 + $i;               
}
```